# Why cannot python's unittest discover _ALL_ tests (including files that start with a number)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a simple python test:

```
import unittest
class TestAsdf(unittest.TestCase):
       def test_Asdf(self):
          self.assertTrue(False)
```

in a file **named `01-asdf_test.py`**.

I am trying to run all tests with this command: `python3 -m unittest discover -p "*_test.py"`

But it is apparently failing to discover the test:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

#### My question is

How can I make it discover the test?

#### P.S.

I runs fine if I specify the file explicitly:

```
python3 -m unittest 01-asdf_test.py                                                                                                        Sun 06 Mar 2022 12:32:32 GMT
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_Asdf (01-asdf_test.TestAsdf)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Comment: ``01-asdf_test`` is not a valid module name (or valid identifier, for that matter), so it is natural to skip for discovering *modules* that contain tests. ["Unittest supports simple test discovery. In order to be compatible with test discovery, all of the test files must be modules or packages (including namespace packages) importable from the top-level directory of the project (this means that their filenames must be valid identifiers)."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery)

Comment: Where can I read about valid module names? It **is** a valid module name in the sense that I can import it.

Answer (score 0):

try using `discover(pattern=...)`

```py
testSuite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover(baseDir, pattern='*_test.py', top_level_dir=baseDir)
```

Comment: the default pattern is 'test*.py'.